# How to save edits when using gdal to add field into multi-feature layer?

Tags: python, gdal, shapefile

I am using the following code to create a new field in a shapefile and want to change its value：

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import ogr
root_path = "xxxxxxxxxxx" # root path
if __name__=='__main__':    
    gdal.UseExceptions()
    ogr.RegisterAll()
    gdal.SetConfigOption("SHAPE_ENCODING", "UTF-8")
    gdal.SetConfigOption("GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8", "YES") 
    oDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
    file_list = os.listdir(root_path)
    for dir in file_list:
        if dir.endswith('.shp'):
            oDS = ogr.Open(root_path+dir, 0)
            lyr = oDS.GetLayer()
            LD = lyr.GetLayerDefn()
            lyr.ResetReading()
            print(LD.GetFieldCount())
            if LD.GetFieldIndex('Item_Code') == -1:
                Field = ogr.FieldDefn('Item_Code', ogr.OFTString)
                Field.SetWidth(15)
                LD.AddFieldDefn(Field)
                print(lyr.schema[13].name)
                for feature in lyr:
                    if dir.split('.')[0].startswith('GBZ'):
                        print(feature.SetField('Item_Code', dir.split('.')[0][:15]))
                    elif dir.split('.')[0].startswith('XM'):
                        print(feature.SetField('Item_Code', dir.split('.')[0][:14]))
                    else:
                        print('error')
                    print("once")
                    print(lyr.SetFeature(feature))
                    print(lyr.SyncToDisk())
            oDS.Destroy()
```

The results are:
13, Item_Code, None, once, 6, 0
It seems 6 represents a failure in [official documents.](https://gdal.org/api/vector_c_api.html#c.OGRERR_FAILURE)
And after the script finished its job, I examined the shapefile using QGIS, not surprisingly no change was found.
So, how can I save my edits? It seems the layer was already changed when I use the code `print(lyr.schema[13].name)`, all I need is to save the edits.

The official documents are also quite confusing, like [osgeo.ogr.Open()](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.ogr.html#osgeo.ogr.Open) and [gdal.OpenEx()](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.OpenEx). Besides, the [layer class](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.ogr.html#osgeo.ogr.Layer) has [Update method](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.ogr.html#osgeo.ogr.Layer.Update), [UpdateFeature method](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.ogr.html#osgeo.ogr.Layer.UpdateFeature), [UpsertFeature method](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.ogr.html#osgeo.ogr.Layer.UpsertFeature), but when I use the layer class, I only got [Update method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYSAF.png)

Environment:

- QGIS: 3.26.3
- PYTHON: 3.7.9 (64-bit)
- GDAL: 3.0.4